# chatbot botman studio Not Found

Tags: php

I integrated botman studio in localhost and it worked perfectly, but when deploying to my online server, I got the error:
**Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request**.

After some analyzes, I have the impression that
**"use App \ Http \ Controllers \ BotManController;"** does not load at botman.php file level.

What to do in this case?

Comment: The `use` statement does not load anything, it just defines a short alias to refer to the class. Is whatever web server you're using configured as required by the product?

Comment: Sounds to me you are not including any autoloading file. How does your entrypoint php file look like?

Comment: That may be an autoloader setup issue or any other thing. Please start by extracting a [mcve] from your project. Also note that people here have no idea what your environment looks like overall. As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: An auto-loading issue would throw a class not found exception, which could reveal as status 500. We're getting status 404 here, seemingly triggered by Apache.

Comment: @ferdynator 
my botman.php file which with a use App\Http\Controllers\BotManController;
<?php
use App\Http\Controllers\BotManController;
$botman = resolve('botman');

$botman->hears('Hi', function ($bot) {
    $bot->reply('Hello!');
});
$botman->hears('Start conversation', BotManController::class.'@startConversation');